# How would you rewrite this multi-arg function, eventually point free style?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm new to Ramda and functional programming and I'm wondering how would someone improve the code below or convert it to point free style

```
const doc = {
  passwordRecovery: {
    requested: true,
    expiresAt: new Date(Date.now() + 1000).toISOString(),
    code: 'abc'
  }
}

const req = {
  password: '123',
  passwordRecovery: {
    code: 'abc'
  }
}

const pathCode = R.path(['passwordRecovery', 'code'])
const isValidCode = R.curry(
    (doc, req) => R.all(
        R.hasPath(['passwordRecovery', 'code'], req),
        R.pathEq(['passwordRecovery', 'requested'], true, doc),
        R.compose(R.complement(R.isNil), pathCode)(doc),
        R.equals(pathCode(req), pathCode(doc)),
        R.pipe(
            R.path(['passwordRecovery', 'expiresAt']),
            Date.parse,
            R.gte(R.__, Date.now()),
        )(doc)
    )
);

isValidCode(doc)(req)
```

Comment: One would improve it by trying *not* to make it [point-less](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree#Problems_with_pointfree). `doc` and `req` are both used multiple times, so it's a good idea to have names to refer to them.

Answer (score 5):

Couple of suggestions:

#### Avoid confusion

People unfamiliar with currying often say the same thing: why do `add(1)(2)` when you can just do `add(1, 2)`? They're right. That example doesn't do justice to currying at all.

If your team is just about getting acquainted with functional programming, don't make it unnecessary confusing to them. If you can supply all arguments in one go, just do it:

```
isValidCode(doc, req); // not isValidCode(doc)(req);
```

#### Don't use Ramda for the sake of using Ramda

This: `R.equals(pathCode(req), pathCode(doc))` is the same as: `pathCode(req) === pathCode(doc)`.

If you do want to use Ramda, consider [`eqBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#eqBy) instead:

```
eqBy(pathCode, req, code);
```

#### Pointfree is not the only way

It certainly is an interesting way to write functions but it cannot be a goal. Say you need to check that `a` is equal to `'foo'` and `b` is equal to `'bar'`:

Is this pointfree function:

```
const fn = useWith(and, [equals('foo'), equals('bar')]);
```

Any better than this:

```
const fn = (a, b) => a === 'foo' && b === 'bar';
```

?

#### Is `all` correctly invoked?

According to the doc, [`all`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#all) takes a function and a list:

```
all(x => x === 42)([41, 42, 43]);
```

Unless I'm mistaken what you've done is to invoke `all` with the result of each function call. e.g.

```
all(true, false, true, ...);
```

#### Avoid the `__` placeholder

`gte(__, Date.now())` can be changed to `flip(gte)(Date.now())`

#### Be consistent

In one case you allow a path to be set to `undefined`:

```
// true even for `{passwordRecovery: {code: undefined}}`
hasPath(['passwordRecovery', 'code'], req);
```

Whereas in the other you don't:

```
compose(R.complement(R.isNil), pathCode)(doc)
```

Being consistent would allow this:

```
const notNil = complement(isNil);
both(pathSatisfies(notNil, pathCode), req, doc)
```

Comment: While I generally agree with this, I have mixed feelings about the placeholder vs `flip`.  And the currying might be legitimate if the OP is going to reuse the function generated by `isValidCode (doc)` for multiple invocations.  Of course even then, unless there was a need to call it *both* ways, a manual currying would beat `R.curry`.

Comment: I seem to remember discussions about deprecating the placeholder. So I’m suggesting getting used to work without it. Wrt currying I’m just trying to say that there isn’t much point in supplying the arguments “one by one” if you can give them all in one go straight away. The function should still remain curried though.

Comment: There have been such discussions, but that's usually tied to discussions of switching to plain currying rather than Ramda's rather magic version.  As to currying, I would only curry it if there is some reason to supply the arguments one-by-one.  And I would do it manually unless for some reason I really needed both styles.  That's much more likely in library code than in application code like this.

Comment: currying is all about partial application, which defers the evaluation of the actual function body. You can't do that with statements and you can't pass statements around like data either. So whenever you need these properties, you might want to use the curried form.

Comment: @bob Just to clarify: all I'm saying is that for a curried function of two arguments such as `add`, if you have the two numbers at hand already, there's little value in doing `add(1)(2)` instead of `add(1, 2)`. It's an example that confuses beginners IMHO. A better example of currying would be `[1,2,3].map(add(1))`

Comment: Yes, but I missed the buzzwords partial application and first class func/passing around like data. When people talk about point-free than they actually talk about the result of what happens when you apply curried functions along with higher order combinators. Point-free is something that suddenly happens to your code, not something you aim at..

Comment: @bob: while one hopes that point-free suddenly happens, I just did my umpteenth code review pointing out that `callback(x => foo(x))` is better written `callback(foo)`.  So it doesn't necessarily happen to all developers, even when it should!

Comment: @ScottSauyet I actually utilize redundant eta abstraction sometimes. I think point-free rarely comes in pure form and it doesn't have to. It mainly depends on what common combinators you can apply in a specific scenario. The crucial thing is probably that your combinators are really common. Nobody understands your point-free code if it uses some of the rarer birds... Btw, I never heard of _umpteenth _ - added to my vocabulary.

Comment: @bob: There are plenty of times to use the eta abstraction.  The trouble is in teaching junior folks that eta reduction can often improve their code.  I think *upteenth* is a fairly common Americanism, but it might be regional to my New England area.  It has a similar flavor to me of when I was a grad student and we aped some well known mathematician who used to use phrases like "all foos can be built out of 100 bars, for some value of 100" rather than "there is some finite `n` such that all foos can be built out of `n` bars."  "umpteenth" feels similar to "for some value of 100".

Answer (score 3):

The points from Bergi and customcommander are all good.

Mainly I would ask why you want to use Ramda for this.  Ramda has many benefits, but it's meant to be used only when it improves your code.  Here I think there is a much cleaner option using destructured and default parameters:

```js
const isValidCode = (
  {passwordRecovery: {code, requested, expiresAt} = {}}, // doc
  {passwordRecovery: {code: reqCode} = {}}               // req
) => reqCode != null 
  && code != null
  && reqCode == code
  && requested != null
  && expiresAt >= new Date (Date .now ()) .toISOString ()

const doc1 = {passwordRecovery: {requested: true, expiresAt: new Date(Date.now() + 1000).toISOString(), code: 'abc'}}
const req1 = {password: '123', passwordRecovery: {code: 'abc'}}

const doc2 = {passwordRecovery: {expiresAt: new Date(Date.now() + 1000).toISOString(), code: 'abc'}}
const req2 = {password: '123', passwordRecovery: {code: 'abcd'}}

console .log (
  isValidCode (doc1, req1), // true
  isValidCode (doc1, req2), // false
  isValidCode (doc2, req1)  // false
)
```

This seems tremendously more readable to me than the original.

### Update

As Aadit points out in the comments, that last line would be better written

```js
  && expiresAt >= new Date () .toISOString ()
```

Or if there's a good reason to compare them directly as timestamps, it could be

```js
  && Date .parse (expiresAt)  >= Date .now ()
```

Comment: An addendum. I just noticed that this is redundant: `reqCode != null && code != null && reqCode == code`.  You could could drop one of the null checks.

Comment: Why write `new Date(Date.now())`? Isn't it the same as `new Date()`?

Comment: Also, if you're comparing dates then you should compare their `.getTime()` values instead of comparing their `.toISOString()` values.

Comment: @AaditMShah: that was just copied from the original.  There is no reason for it.  As to `.getTime()` vs `.toISOString()`, that's not so clear to me.  One of the benefits of the ISO format is that it's designed to be sortable.  So either should work.  And it comes down to parsing the String format and taking its timestamp to compare to `Date.now()` or formatting `new Date()` to compare to the existing ISO string.  Without testing, I would expect the formatting to be more efficient than the parsing, and I can see no other important reason to choose the other.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out that you just copied the code from the OP. I missed that.

Comment: @AaditMShah: "The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z"." -- from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)